# How to use es5 in a project which includes typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, ecmascript-6

I have an Angular2 based project which uses TypeScript that compiles to es5 and is using the AOT compiler. The AOT compiler has to have a local typescript installed, otherwise, I get:

```
module.js:457
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'typescript'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:455:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:403:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

But when I have this installed, I get loads of errors because of the es5 lack of definitions for es6 features e.g.

```
Error at C:/Users/George/Source/Repos/docs/node_modules/@types/mongodb/index.d.ts:17:64: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
Error at C:/Users/George/Source/Repos/docs/node_modules/@types/mongodb/index.d.ts:21:57: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
Error at C:/Users/George/Source/Repos/docs/node_modules/@types/mongodb/index.d.ts:165:78: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
Error at C:/Users/George/Source/Repos/docs/node_modules/@types/mongodb/index.d.ts:171:92: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
Error at C:/Users/George/Source/Repos/docs/node_modules/@types/mongodb/index.d.ts:175:34: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
Error at C:/Users/George/Source/Repos/docs/node_modules/@types/mongodb/index.d.ts:182:20: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
Error at C:/Users/George/Source/Repos/docs/node_modules/@types/mongodb/index.d.ts:186:86: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
Error at C:/Users/George/Source/Repos/docs/node_modules/@types/mongodb/index.d.ts:190:72: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
```

However, if I add the `es6-promise` definitions, then I get the following errors:

```
node_modules/@types/es6-promise/index.d.ts(11,15): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Promise'.
node_modules/@types/es6-promise/index.d.ts(42,19): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Promise'.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(4852,11): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Promise'.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(5175,11): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Promise'.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(5342,13): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Promise'.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(5560,11): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Promise'.
```

What should I be doing to satisfy all these requirements? You can see the full repo on [GitHub](https://github.com/georgeedwards/docs/tree/performance).

Comment: Hi, you can to try: 1. tsconfig.json ->{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": false
  }
}, 2. Check all type difinitions: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/angularjs

Comment: @DmitryMatrosov Not sure what you mean? I have a tsconfig, it looks like [this](https://github.com/georgeedwards/docs/blob/performance/client/tsconfig-aot.json)

Comment: ok, you need open  C:/Users/George/Source/Repos/docs/node_modules/@types/mongodb/index.d.ts, and check all reference /// <reference path="../angular/index.d.ts" />